# array.median() function returns wrong result

Tags: pine-script

The new [array.median()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dmedian) function calculates the wrong result.

In the example script below, the median calculated by PineScript is 12.20
The correct result should be 10.90

This script demonstrates the wrong behavior in PineScript

```
//@version=4
study("Median test")

// Define array
a = array.new_float()

// Fill array with values
array.push(a,0.6)
array.push(a,12.2)
array.push(a,6)
array.push(a,5.6)
array.push(a,4.1)
array.push(a,8.9)
array.push(a,5)
array.push(a,0.5)
array.push(a,0.2)
array.push(a,14.2)
array.push(a,6.2)
array.push(a,10)
array.push(a,2.5)
array.push(a,5)
array.push(a,9.7)
array.push(a,63)
array.push(a,2.3)
array.push(a,13)
array.push(a,23)
array.push(a,10.9)
array.push(a,13.7)
array.push(a,0.6)
array.push(a,26.4)
array.push(a,49)
array.push(a,40.3)
array.push(a,44)
array.push(a,25.9)
array.push(a,3.6)
array.push(a,3)
array.push(a,48)
array.push(a,38.3)
array.push(a,6.7)
array.push(a,82.4)
array.push(a,82)
array.push(a,31.9)
array.push(a,20.8)
array.push(a,1.6)
array.push(a,15.8)
array.push(a,40.2)
array.push(a,0.8)
array.push(a,41.9)
array.push(a,33.1)
array.push(a,30.8)
array.push(a,1.4)
array.push(a,24.5)
array.push(a,8.9)
array.push(a,3.9)
array.push(a,18.5)
array.push(a,8.2)

// Calculate the median
// The median calculated by PineScript is 12.20 and is wrong.
// The correct median is 10.90
// When the median is calculated in Excel or an online resource like these below, the result is 10.90
// http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/median/
// https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/mean-median-mode.php
med = array.median(a) 

// Plot the median
plot(med, title="Wrong median")
```

The correct result can be verified by calculating the median in Excel, or an online tool like
http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/median/
https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/mean-median-mode.php

If you'd like to calculate it yourself, this is the dataset from the script

```
0.6
12.2
6
5.6
4.1
8.9
5
0.5
0.2
14.2
6.2
10
2.5
5
9.7
63
2.3
13
23
10.9
13.7
0.6
26.4
49
40.3
44
25.9
3.6
3
48
38.3
6.7
82.4
82
31.9
20.8
1.6
15.8
40.2
0.8
41.9
33.1
30.8
1.4
24.5
8.9
3.9
18.5
8.2
```

Comment: Thx for this. We'll investigate.

Comment: The bug was fixed.